# recreating password meter like slack website

Tags: javascript, jquery, passwords

Does anyone know what password meter plugin is slack using?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are using a plugin called: "**zxcvbn**"

https://github.com/dropbox/zxcvbn